# How to use {{{}}} syntax for trusted html?

Tags: angularjs

Handlebar's `{{expression}}` form HTML-escapes values returned while its `{{{expression}}}` form does not. Is there any way to add this feature to AngualarJS templates so that we can use `{{expression}}` for regular sanitized output and `{{{expression}}}` for trusted, non-escaped HTML expressions?

By the way, I am familiar with `ng-bind-html` directive.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want to do? Your question is rather vague.

Comment: Theoretically (I didn't try this and my time wouldn't allow me to do it now)  one could change/extend the Angular's templating model to allow such a thing. That said, I personally think non-escaped HTML in templates are an exception case, that should be used sparingly and with special care, and such a mod would go against this.

Answer (score 4):

**Answer**: The short answer is no.  I've never come across such a configuration.  You can't get {{{}}} to work in Angular.

**Helpful workaround**: It is not possible to get unescaped/unsanitized HTML into a view through the scope without using the ng-bind-html directive.  You could add either a helper function to your controller or add a filter that might make it a little easier to use ng-bind-html ([Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wu7dkC?p=preview)), but you still seem to need ng-bind-html:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.someHtmlContent = "Label: <input name='test'>";

  $scope.h = function(html) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
  };
}); 

app.filter('trustAsHtml', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MyController">
  <div ng-bind-html="someHtmlContent | trustAsHtml"> 
  </div>

  <div ng-bind-html="h(someHtmlContent)"> 
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @PHPst The answer is "no". You can't do what you want.  The rest of the answer was showing how you can use a filter or a helper function to make it slightly easier to use the ng-bind-html directive, which is necessary to put unescaped HTML into the view.  You need ng-bind-html.

Comment: "… or add a filter that might make it a little easier to use" How does it become easier? It seems to be more messy.

Comment: You are forced the use ng-bind-html no matter what.  You can't do what you would like to do with {{{}}}.  But if you have to use ng-bind-html, as is the case, a filter (trustAsHtml) or helper function (h()) will make it easier to do that directly inside the view without having to put code in the controller that specifically calls $sce.trustAsHtml() on each particular scope variable that you wish to use for unescaped HTML (which you would otherwise have to do, even with ng-bind-html).  That's why it's easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is really an unnecessary problem, and what follows, is an even more unnecessary solution :)  But just for fun, you could do something like the following: parse the HTML and replace all found instances of `{{{` and `}}}` with `ng-bind-html`. I reused the filter approach above to actually do `$sce.trustAsHtml`:

```
app.directive("trust", function($compile){
  return {
    terminal: true,
    priority: 4000,
    link: function(scope, elem){
      var html = elem.html();
      var re = /({{{)([^}]+)(}}})/g;
      var newHtml = html.replace(re, '<span ng-bind-html="$2 | trustAsHtml"></span>');
      elem.html(newHtml);
      elem.removeAttr("trust");
      $compile(elem)(scope);
    }
  };
})
.filter('trustAsHtml', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });
```

Usage is:

```
<div trust>
  {{{html()}}}
  <div>
    {{{foo}}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hEl2Ol1H0O35XKGUnDWu?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to use `{{{}}}`, it is possible:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{{{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}}}');
});
```

However it is not possible to do that only for trusted html. All of your delimiters will change.

Comment: This seem to answer some question, but not this one