# AngularJS: ng-bind-html remove styling

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my app I'm using a `table` and `ng-repeat`. I'm rendering my data, one of columns is rendered with the help of:

```
<div class="cell" data-ng-bind-html="article.Content">
</div>
```

But I have a problem, if I have content like:

```
<div class="page-wrap">123</div>
```

It breaks my whole style (*because page has page-wrap too*).

Is it real to render html, but without rendering style and css style? And how?

like:

```
<div>123</div>
```

Answer (score 17):

I believe what you are saying is that `article.Content` actually contains HTML, and that Angular is stripping out all of the HTML tags.

Your code is close to getting you what you want, but you need to use the $sce service to mark the content with HTML in it as 'safe'.  A simple way to do that is to use this filter.

```
app.filter('trustAsHtml', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });
```

Then use this filter to strip out the classes:

```
app.filter('stripClasses', function() {
  return function(str) {
    return str.replace(/class=['"].*["']/, '');
  }
});
```

The .replace() function strips out any `class="whatever"` from the content, which I think is what you want.

**UPDATE:** Similarly, this could be used to strip out any inline styles:

```
app.filter('stripStyles', function() {
  return function(str) {
    return str.replace(/style=['"].*["']/, '');
  }
});
```

(You need to change the `app.` part of the filter definitions to whatever works for your app. Use whatever prefix/method you use for your .controller() calls.)

If you have several styles or classes to strip, you should go for the non greedy version of the regex which is:

```
str.replace(/class=['"](.*?)["']/g, '')
```

Then you would change your `data-ng-bind-html="article.Content"` to this:

```
<div class="cell" data-ng-bind-html="article.Content | stripClasses | trustAsHtml"></div>
```

Or, for both class and style removal:

```
<div class="cell" data-ng-bind-html="article.Content | stripStyles | stripClasses | trustAsHtml"></div>
```

[This Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/wu7dkC?p=preview) I did for [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28384593/1480995) shows how you can use the trustAsHtml filter and shows how you use the $sce service inside a controller, as well.

Comment: maybe somehow to use regex? which regex i need to delete all attr from all elements?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your problem. Can you create a Plunk at plnkr.co that shows the problem?  Thanks.

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Oh, so you also want to remove  class="page-wrap" from the content?  I get it now.  Gimme a few minutes to deal with that.

Comment: @brabertaser1992 OK, I added another filter that strips out classes, if that is what you want. Try this.

Comment: nice approach, would you improve the answer with stripStyles? in my case they add inline style instead of adding classes.

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo I added it. UpVote if you find it useful, please.